# Offline version of Source code tken from Microsoft TFS

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I get offline version of source code from TFS. I removed files with extensions  *.scc;*.vssscc;*.vspscc; and folders debug;release;obj;bin from project. Still Visual Studio 2010 ask username and password. If I had click on cancel button then offline version is opened. Can I get rid of that username and password window everytime I opened project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to removing those files, you should also open you project files (.csproj or .vbproj) in a text editor and remove this part:

```
<SccProjectName></SccProjectName> 
<SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath> 
<SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath> 
<SccProvider></SccProvider>
```

Then open your solution file (.sln) in a text editor and remove this section:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
   SccNumberOfProjects=..
   SccEnterpriseProvider=..
   SccTeamFoundationServer=..
   ..
   ..
EndGlobalSection
```

You can also do these steps after opening your solution in visual studio:

- From the file menu, select `Source Control/Change Source Control`
- For every project, click `Unbind` button on toolbar.